# "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" - UserDetailsService Setup in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In a Spring Boot application, I have an in-memory Spring Security setup. And it works as desired.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("kevin").password("password1").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("diana").password("password2").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/foos").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/foos/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/foos/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/foos/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

Now, I convert it to a database based approach with the following code.

```
@Entity
class Account {

  enum Role {ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN}

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String userName;

//  @JsonIgnore
  private String password;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
   ...
}
```

The repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long>{

  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
  Optional<Account> findByUserName(@Param("userName") String userName);
}
```

The UserDetailsService:

```
@Component
class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  private AccountRepository accountRepository;

  MyUserDetailsService(AccountRepository accountRepository){
    this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<Account> accountOptional = this.accountRepository.findByUserName(name);
    if(!accountOptional.isPresent())
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(name);

    Account account = accountOptional.get();
    return new User(account.getUserName(), account.getPassword(),
        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(account.getRoles().stream().map(Account.Role::name).toArray(String[]::new)));
  }
}
```

And the modification of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  SecurityConfiguration(MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService){
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);  // <-- replacing the in-memory anthentication setup
  }
  ...
}
```

When I send the same request with **a pair of username and password as the basic authentication** as for the in-memory version, I, however, get the 401 error:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1489430818803,
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext",
  "path": "/foos"
}
```

After reading through some related document and sample code, I can't see the cause of the error. What the error message says is that the user isn't in the Spring Security context. The line of AuthenticationManagerBuilder usage in the  userDetailsService(userDetailsService) shall take care of setting up these users in the SecurityContext, isn't it?

The Spring Boot version is 1.4.3.RELEASE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove this `preAuthorize` annotation from the `crud repository`. this method is used when ever you are trying to login but with the `preauthorize` annotation it expects a user to be logged in.

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
  Optional<Account> findByUserName(@Param("userName") String userName);
```

and i made some changes to the `configure` method in `websecurityconfigureadapter`
you might need to allow access to  the **sign** in and **login** urls in the **configure** method without login permission.

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeUrls()
        .antMatchers("/signup","/about").permitAll() // #4
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") // #6
        .anyRequest().authenticated() // 7
        .and()
    .formLogin()  // #8
        .loginUrl("/login") // #9
        .permitAll(); // #5
  }
```

be careful when requiring admin permission to `/foo/**`  these kind of **urls** this tells that **all urls begin with `foo`** are only allowed for admins.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It works after removing the preAuhorize annotation. The error message is about authentication, but not authorization. Also, the path stated in the error response message is about foo, but not account. In regarding of the URLs security configuration, it also can be defined with http methods.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is, that your repository finder is annotated with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")`. This method is invoked before a request can be (fully) authenticated, so it can never pass the check and the exception is raised even if you pass the proper credentials.

Another point is, do you really want to expose your user account data as ReST resources? At the moment a request like `curl http://localhost:8080/accounts` will return all your user data as JSON+HAL response, even to anonymous users.

It would return something like:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "accounts" : [ {
      "userName" : "admin",
      "password" : "admin",
      "roles" : [ "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN" ],
      "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/accounts/1"
    },
    "account" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/accounts/1"
    }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/accounts"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/accounts"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/accounts/search"
    }
  }
}
```

So `@RepositoryRestResource` is dangerous here, using `@Repository` is the way to go if you just want to use the database table to auth your requests.

For details see the [documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/).

Even if you removed the passwords from the responses as your code suggests (with the commented `@JsonIgnore` annotation in your `Account` class) you would expose security related information like usernames and roles. Beside that it's a bad practice to "abuse" your Entity to shape your response object. Better use [Projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) instead.

If you want to keep your `/accounts` endpoint you should also secure it by maybe at least adding `.antMatchers("/accounts/**").hasRole("ADMIN")` to your config.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, Kevin. And thanks for the information. In terms of the security configuration for Account entity, I did have all my code up here. I do have endpont security setup. Only the ADMIN role can access to those end-points is too restricted. Anyone shall be able to create a new account and edit it for general use cases.

Comment: I agree that more refined security only can be done with a controller. For example, a creation and an editing operation invoke the same repository method save. While anyone shall be allowed to create a user data, only the user self or someone with the ADMIN role can edit a user data.

Comment: Ok. :) The main thing is that you are aware of the risks.

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem lies in the `UserDetailService.loadUseByUsername` - there you call:

```
Optional<Account> accountOptional = this.accountRepository.findByUserName(name);
```

and it is being done during te authorization process. But the `accountRepository` method is annotated with `PreAuthorize` - and can be called only from `context` containing `Authentication Object`.

Do a simple test to understand it:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long>{

  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
  Page<Account> findAll(Pageable pageable);

  Optional<Account> findByUserName(@Param("userName") String userName);
}
```

Then check, that you can query for all users correctly. The only problem is in the *recursive* nature of `findByUserName` method.

Cheers!